# label creation not positioned in the dwg

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

I have a function that gets called to create labels and position them to simulate dimensions in a drawing (like a cad front view); however they all get positioned in the top left even though the x and y coordinates are being sent correctly via the call function. I've hit a wall on this one and would appreciate any help.[see screenshot I took and you'll notice that all the labels are scrunched up in the top left corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDlUN.png)

All the dwg gets added to the CGContext

Here's my function:

```
    public func drawText(ctx: CGContext,
                    txtCol:UIColor,
                    text:String,
                    posX:Double,
                    posY:Double,
                    rotation:Double,
                    fill:Bool) -> CGContext {

    let label = UILabel()
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.text = text
    label.textColor = txtCol
    label.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi / 2)
    if fill {
        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    }
    label.draw(CGRect(x: CGFloat(posX), y: CGFloat(posY), width: 100, height: 30))
    label.layer.render(in: ctx)
    return ctx
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As renderInContext: documentation states : "Renders in the coordinate space of the layer." This means the frame origin of your layer/view is ignored.
You might want to use `CGContextTranslateCTM` before calling `label.layer.render(in: ctx)`. Remember to save and restore the CTM on each call using `CGContextSaveGState` and `CGContextRestoreGState`.

Also, I doubt the need to call `label.draw(CGRect(x: CGFloat(posX), y: CGFloat(posY), width: 100, height: 30))`. Since it should not be call manually.

Comment: I used the `label.drawText(in: CGRect(x: CGFloat(posX), y: CGFloat(posY), width: 100, height: 30))` and it seemed to output ok - although the `label.backgroundColor` and `label.transform` seem to be ignored...